# code to replace emoticons by "SAD" or "HAPPY" not working properly

Tags: python, nltk, text-processing

So I wanted to replace all the happy emoticons with "HAPPY" and vice versa "SAD" for sad emoticons for a text file. But the code isnt working properly. Though it detects smileys (as of now :-) ), but in the below example its not replacing the emoticon with text, its simply appending the text and that too its appending it two times for reasons I dont seem to understand.

```
dict_sad={":-(":"SAD", ":(":"SAD", ":-|":"SAD",  ";-(":"SAD", ";-<":"SAD", "|-{":"SAD"}
dict_happy={":-)":"HAPPY",":)":"HAPPY", ":o)":"HAPPY",":-}":"HAPPY",";-}":"HAPPY",":->":"HAPPY",";-)":"HAPPY"}

#THE INPUT TEXT#
a="guys beautifully done :-)" 

for i in a.split():
    for j in dict_happy.keys():
        if set(j).issubset(set(i)):
            print "HAPPY"
            continue
    for k in dict_sad.keys():
        if set(k).issubset(set(i)):
            print "SAD"
            continue
    if str(i)==i.decode('utf-8','replace'):
       print i
```

THE INPUT TEXT

```
a="guys beautifully done :-)"
```

OUTPUT ("HAPPY" is coming two times, also the emoticon isnt getting away)

```
guys
-
beautifully
done
HAPPY
HAPPY
:-)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
guys
beautifully
done
HAPPY
```

Comment: Why are you using sets at all here? You are creating sets of characters, and both `set(':)')` is a subset of `set(':-)')` so that matches just like `set('):')` would.

Comment: why `-` after guys??? in expected output??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are turning *each word* and *each emoticon* to a set; this means you are looking for overlap of individual characters. You probably wanted uses exact matches at most:

```
for i in a.split():
    for j in dict_happy:
        if j == i:
            print "HAPPY"
            continue
    for k in dict_sad:
        if k == i:
            print "SAD"
            continue
```

You can iterate over dictionaries *directly*, no need to call `.keys()` there. You don't actually appear to be using the dictionary values; you could just do:

```
for word in a.split():
    if word in dict_happy:
        print "HAPPY"
    if word in dict_sad:
        print "SAD"
```

and then perhaps use sets instead of dictionaries. This then can be reduced to:

```
words = set(a.split())
if dict_happy.viewkeys() & words:
    print "HAPPY"
if dict_sad.viewkeys() & words:
    print "SAD"
```

using the [dictionary view](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) on the keys as a set. Still, it would still be better to use sets then:

```
sad_emoticons = {":-(", ":(", ":-|", ";-(", ";-<", "|-{"}
happy_emoticons = {":-)", ":)", ":o)", ":-}", ";-}", ":->", ";-)"}

words = set(a.split())
if sad_emoticons & words:
    print "HAPPY"
if happy_emoticons & words:
    print "SAD"
```

If you wanted to remove the emoticon from the text, you'll have to filter the words:

```
for word in a.split():
    if word in dict_happy:
        print "HAPPY"
    elif word in dict_sad:
        print "SAD"
    else:
        print word
```

or better still, combine the two dictionaries and use `dict.get()`:

```
emoticons = {
    ":-(": "SAD", ":(": "SAD", ":-|": "SAD", 
    ";-(": "SAD", ";-<": "SAD", "|-{": "SAD",
    ":-)": "HAPPY",":)": "HAPPY", ":o)": "HAPPY",
    ":-}": "HAPPY", ";-}": "HAPPY", ":->": "HAPPY",
    ";-)": "HAPPY"
}

for word in a.split():
    print emoticons.get(word, word)
```

Here I pass in the current word both as the look-up key and the default; if the current word is not an emoticon, the word itself is printed, otherwise the word `SAD` or `HAPPY` is printed instead.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. But if I append "if str(i)==i.decode('utf-8','replace'):
           print i
" to you code, its not escaping the emoticon. Though "HAPPY" is getting printed once, but still emoticon is not going away. OUTPUT : "guys
-
beautifully
done
HAPPY
:-)
"

Comment: @rzach: the emoticon is just *ASCII text*. Encoding it to UTF8 is not going to make it go away, no.

Comment: But then how do I print the sentence, the purpose is to print sentence along with replacement of emoticons by either HAPPY/SAD. Also ::: AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'intersection'.

Comment: @Hackaholic: if all you wanted to do was print `HAPPY` or `SAD` based on a sentence, using a set to do a simply intersection is more efficient.

Comment: but OP's dosent want that, just want to replace the emotion with either happy or sad

Comment: @Hackaholic: what the OP wanted was muddled and unclear at first. As such, I covered many possible bases.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dictionaries i've used lists. Makes the code a bit simpler:

```
list_sad = [":(", ":-("]
list_happy = [":)", ":-)"]

a = "guys beautifully done :-)" 

for i in a.split():
    if i in list_sad:
        print ("SAD")
    elif i in list_happy:
        print ("HAPPY")
    else:
        print (i)
```

Comment: Better to use *sets* here; membership tests on a list take a linear scan, sets use hashing (like dictionaries) giving you constant-time lookups.